# How to get to central Berlin from Schoenefeld Airport

Tags: airport-transfer, berlin, sxf

I am planning to arrive to Berlin to Schoenefeld Airport and need a hint on how to get to central Berlin. I am going to stay at Kubrat Hotel near Check Point Charlie.

Comment: Related: [How to get to Berlin Schönefeld airport at 5 in the morning by public transport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56900)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Kubrat Hotel (Checkpoint Charlie) at the Leipziger Straße 21:
You use the Airport Express RE7 or RB14 in direction Hauptbahnhof which is coming each hour. You leave the train at Friedrichstraße after 20-25 min and enter the U6 in direction Alt-Mariendorf. After two stations you leave the U6 at Stadtmitte. You go in direction Leipziger Straße, after 60m you are directly in vicinity of the Hotel.

Nice stay.

Comment: Thanks to all for the help. It was great to have a hand on this.

Comment: +1 The way from Friedrichstraße to Leipziger Straße is also completely walkable, should you want to.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Maps](http://goo.gl/maps/MRe55) route planner has you covered. The journey will take around 45 minutes.

Comment: Could you at least elaborate in your answer? I know Google's pretty reliable, but if the link breaks or maps are down, it's nice to have the directions/instructions in the answer.

Comment: Thorsten S. already spelled it out. I would also argue that train/bus schedules tend to change very often, so a link/suggestion to use Google Maps is better in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

Take the RE7 Airport Express and do not take the S-Bahn. It stops very often it will take ages.