# How to get to Berlin Schönefeld airport at 5 in the morning by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, berlin, sxf

I have really early flight from Berlin Schönefeld airport (SXF). I don't use taxi, and I can't find the schedules of public transport that early.

How can I get to Berlin airport at 5 in the morning by public transport?

I am departing from Berlin, on Sunday morning in December.

Comment: from where? on which day?

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 added the information

Comment: where in Berlin? HBF? or anywhere? and which airport? SXF or TXL?

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 SXF. I dont know yet where I am going to stay. I can choose a place, in the city centre, acording to the best place to leave to the airport

Comment: S-Bahn Lines S45 and S9 run to the airport and run 24hours on weekends every 30min

Comment: Why not stay in an airport hotel?

Comment: @CountIblis Is there a decent hotel? SXF doesn't really feel like a real airport.

Comment: @Relaxed [This map](http://www.booking.com/airport/de/sxf.html) shows two hotels nearby, the Holiday inn and the Leonardo hotel.

Comment: airport hotels can be a good option but hotels are usually expensive compared with cheaper accommodation in the city + public transport, plus you still need to get there the night before so depends on any plans one might have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [Berlin Airport Public Transport Page](http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/travellers-sxf/to-and-from/buses-and-trains/local-public-transport/)

**S-Bahn Trains** are your best bet (these run every 24 hours at 30 min intervals at night on weekends)

> **S9** every 20 minutes (Pankow – Schönhauser Allee – Ostkreuz – Schöneweide – Adlershof – Flughafen Schönefeld)
>
> **S45** every 20 minutes (Südkreuz – Neukölln – Baumschulenweg – Schöneweide – Adlershof – Flughafen Schönefeld)

More information from the [S-Bahn website](http://www.s-bahn-berlin.de/en/arrival-and-departure/airports)

Alternatively you can take regional trains or bus

More information on buses on the [VBB website](http://www.vbb.de/en/article/airport-sxf/to-from-airport-sxf/7562.html)

Try visiting those websites and running a query with the exact date you plan to travel with arrival time of 5am.  Catch is you need to enter the place you are traveling from.  This might help you decide where to stay.  But from my experience catching S-Bahn trains around the city center is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Some S-Bahn/U-Bahn lines operate all night long, at least on some days, and there is also a network of night buses. Otherwise, the regular S-Bahn service starts at 04:30 so depending on where you are staying the first S-Bahn (perhaps combined with a bus) could be the solution.

In addition to all the resources mentioned by EdmundYeung99, you can simply use the [BVG journey planner](http://www.bvg.de/en/) to find a route. It works just fine even for night buses, regional trains and S-Bahn trains even though the latter are not operated by the BVG.